# How to print the same document to multiple printers

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any Way to print the same document to multiple printers by only one click using Javascript or Jquery ?

Comment: "unclear what you're asking" I'd say.

Answer (score 2):

No, JavaScript can't do anything other than invoke the browser's print dialog